# Eclipse not allowing creation of AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse

before downvoting/ marking as duplicate, please note that I have gone through similar questions on SOF and was unable to find the answer. I am trying to create an AVD I have downloaded the eclipse with adt plugin (eclipse for android develoeprs). Now when I try to create a new AVD, it throws an error.

```
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] Invalid argument size '512M'
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] 
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] mksdcard: create a blank FAT32 image to be used with the Android emulator
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] usage: mksdcard [-l label] <size> <file>
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] 
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager]   if <size> is a simple integer, it specifies a size in bytes
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager]   if <size> is an integer followed by 'K', it specifies a size in KiB
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager]   if <size> is an integer followed by 'M', it specifies a size in MiB
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager]   if <size> is an integer followed by 'G', it specifies a size in GiB
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] 
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] Minimum size is 9M. The Android emulator cannot use smaller images.
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] Maximum size is 1099511627264 bytes, 1073741823K, 1048575M or 1023G
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2013-12-04 11:46:38 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

I have tried this with 3 differnt versions of eclipse (indigo, kepler and +adt). I was able to create AVDs yesterday, now I dont know the problem... I havent changed anything..

Comment: can you check your SDK manager that you 've installed all required tools fully.

Comment: I did... It was working fine for weeks... I donno what happened today.. I deleted old AVD and now BOOM...

Comment: check the adt plugin for updates Window-->Check for updates

Comment: And it works.... I created an new DEvice and then created avd based on it... Then, i deleted the old device and nwo I am able to create any other AVD.. I think I will have to file a bug report  :P.. Anyways .. thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

if UBUNTU:
in my case, I was using a 64-bit Linux install, which did not have the ia32-libs package installed by default. The mksdcard utility will not run without this package. After installing it, I was able to build the AVD without a problem using the AVD manager.

in normal case:

```
alex@alex-desktop:~$ mksdcard 1024M ./sdcard.iso
bash: /home/alex/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/mksdcard: No such file or directory
alex@alex-desktop:~$ sudo android create avd -n my_avd -t 1 -c 1024M
```

I have found this problem & i find a way first:

```
cd /home/alex/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/
```

then write this:

```
sudo chmod 755 mksdcard
mksdcard 1024M ./sdcard.iso
sudo android create avd -n my_avd -t 1 -c 1024M
```

it should work :)